# Mouse hover to open menga menu in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, megamenu

I am new to Angular 6 and Bootstrap ,Here I have a Navigation bar with 3 nav items .

In this I have a nav item named as Store ,When User mouse hover on the Store I need to show a mega menu .mega menu should have the with of the nav bar .

I have tried something but I could not get what I expected .

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q4p7cc?file=src%2Fstyles.css

can anyone help me to solve this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[try solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mega-minu-ytmxye)

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div *ngFor="let cat of category" class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Link {{cat.catnumber}}
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div *ngFor="let catg of cat.nest" class="column">
                    <h3>Category {{cat.catnumber}} {{catg.link}} </h3>
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

style.css:

```
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content .header {
    background: red;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    background: yello;
    display: block;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 250px;
}

.column a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.column a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Bro ,I am looking for something like this https://codepen.io/JacobLett/full/jaaQYG @UnluckyAj

Comment: Okay ,Bro waiting @UnluckyAj

Comment: Brooooooooooooooooooooooooo @UnluckyAj

Comment: i have edited the code please check and respond back.